# Book on periodic Schrödinger operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

I am looking for good books about the spectral theory of  periodic (1-dimensional) Schrödinger operators on a compact interval.

A good reference I found was Reed/Simon Analysis of Operators (and a book by Eastham on periodic Sturm-Liouville problems). I definitely like this reference, but the problem is that this is really the last chapter of the four books they wrote, so they use a lot of cross references to all other books. Also, I think their style is not the style that I like the most.So, are there more books about this topic available that you could recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this book by Gerald Teschl](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/).

Comment: Deleting my previous comment, and then this one a bit later...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Section 5.6 of my [ode book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/) is what you are looking for. There is also a new more comprehensive book [Periodic Differential Operators](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-3-0348-0527-8) by Brown, Eastham, and Schmidt.